# How to create a type that implement IDictionary<'K, 'V> and IEnumerable<'V>

Tags: f#

I want to create a read-only keyed collection that implements IDictionary<'K, 'V> and IEnumerable<'V>. Taking the obvious approach I get the following error:

`This type implements or inherits the same interface at different generic instantiations 'IEnumerable<'V>' and 'IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<'K,'V>>'. This is not permitted in this version of F#.`

Is there a different way of achieving this?

**EDIT** - Since this seems to be an insurmountable limitation of F#, what would be an idiomatic way of achieving this? One thought that comes to mind is providing members that return the desired view of the data, e.g., member x.List : IList<'V> and member x.Dict : IDictionary<'K, 'V>. Object expressions could be used to provide the implementations. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid not. The CLR allows implementation of multiple interfaces of course (even of the same base type), but not the F# language. I believe you won't have any problems if you write the class in C#, but F# is going to give you problems in the current version.

Answer (score 7):

One relatively easy approach is to expose the implementation of the two interfaces as members of the type you are writing. This can be done quite nicely using *object expressions* or just by writing a piece of code that constructs some type and returns it as the result. The second approach would look like this:

```
type MyCollection<'K, 'V when 'K : equality>(keys:list<'K>, values:list<'V>) =
  member x.Dictionary = 
    Seq.zip keys values |> dict
  member x.Enumerable = 
    values |> List.toSeq
```

The first approach (if you want to implement methods of the interfaces directly would look roughly like this:

```
type MyCollection<'K, 'V when 'K : equality>(keys:list<'K>, values:list<'V>) =
  member x.Dictionary = 
    { new IDictionary<'K, 'V> with 
        member d.Add(k, v) = ... }            
  member x.Enumerable = 
    // Similarly for IEnumerable
    values |> List.toSeq
```

Exposing the implementations as functions in a module as mentioned by kvb is also a great option - I think that many of the standard F# library types actually do both of the options (so that the user can choose the style he/she prefers). This can be added like this:

```
module MyCollection = 
  let toDict (a:MyCollection<_, _>) = a.Dictionary
```

Answer (score 2):

As Noldorin says, this is not possible.  One idiomatic approach is to provide `toSeq` and `toDict` functions on a module with the same name as your type (like `List.toSeq`, `Array.toSeq`, etc.).