# How to inherit the same generic interface twice with different types in F# 3.0

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I am trying to implement object model for [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) using .Net driver [Neo4jClient](http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/wiki/Home). I get an compilation error

> This type implements or inherits the same interface at different generic instantiations `'IRelationshipAllowingParticipantNode<Person>'` and `'IRelationshipAllowingParticipantNode<Company>'`. This is not permitted in this version of F#.

Here is implementation of these interfaces (from Neo4jClient source code)

```cs
public interface IRelationshipAllowingParticipantNode<out TNode>
{
}
public interface IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<out TNode>
    : IRelationshipAllowingParticipantNode<TNode>
{
}
public interface IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<out TNode>
    : IRelationshipAllowingParticipantNode<TNode>
{
}
```

This is my class that does not compile

```
type FollowRelationship(target) =
    inherit Relationship(target)
    interface IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<Person>
    interface IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<Company>

    override this.RelationshipTypeKey
        with get() = "follow"
```

How to be here? How can I avoid this error? Can I use Neo4jClient library from F#?

Comment: What is the definition of the `Relationship` type?

Comment: Definition of `Relationship` type you can find [here](http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/src/f459c385259bccdad11852fd9d2e64911070c843/Neo4jClient/Relationship.cs?at=default) it does not matter in this case

Comment: [One possible solution to the problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3311850/162396)